# Find smallest period from a >1000 digit number

Tags: code-golf

Your job is to take this number as input (although it should work with any other number too):

```
18349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109761834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710976183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097618349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109761834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710976183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097618349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109761834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710976183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097618349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109761834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710976183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097618349570345710975183495703457109751834957
```

and find the smallest period, which is in this case:

```
1834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710976
```

Good luck and have fun!

---

**Clarifications**:

- The input number has in minimum one period and one partial period
- The period always starts at the beginning of the input number
- Period means in this case a sequence of numbers which repeats itself.

Comment: what is the maximum size of the input number? if you meant 1000 is the maximum size, your `>` is facing the wrong way.

Comment: @steveverrill: No, there is no maximum size of the input number per se, but let's limit it to 2^16 digits (because you asked).

Comment: What is a period?

Comment: @FUZxxl in this case: a sequence of numbers which repeats itself.

Comment: @MichaelBolli Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: What you're asking for is clear, but you really should not call it a period: in mathematics, a period only refers to digits _after_ the decimal point repeated _infinitely many times_. As opposite, your test input is an integer and has a finite number of digits.

Comment: @GOTO0 thanks I will remember that in the future!

Comment: Can we assume that there will be at least 1 period in the number. By that, I mean that the number will have at least 1 period and 1 partial period .

Comment: @MartinBüttner The period always starts at the beginning of the string.

Comment: @Optimizer Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## CJam, <s>20</s> 16 bytes

```
Ll:Q{+_Q,*Q#!}=;
```

Reads from STDIN. [Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

The above code will require **O(n<sup>2</sup>)** memory, where **n** is the length of the input. It *will* work with 2<sup>16</sup> digits, as long as you have enough memory.

This can be fixed the the cost of five extra bytes:

```
Ll:Q{+_Q,1$,/)*Q#!}=;
```

#### Example run

```
$ cjam <(echo 'Ll:Q{+_Q,*Q#!}=;') <<< 18349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109761834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710976183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097618349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109761834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710976183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097618349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109761834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710976183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097618349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109761834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710976183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097618349570345710975183495703457109751834957; echo
1834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710976
$ cjam <(echo 'Ll:Q{+_Q,*Q#!}=;') <<< 12345123451; echo
12345
$ cjam <(echo 'Ll:Q{+_Q,*Q#!}=;') <<< 1234512345; echo
12345
$ cjam <(echo 'Ll:Q{+_Q,*Q#!}=;') <<< 123451; echo
12345
```

#### How it works

For input Q, the idea is to repeat the first character len(Q) times and check if the index of Q in the result is 0. If it isn't, repeat the first *two* characters len(Q) times, etc.

```
L                   " Push L := [].                                                       ";
 l:Q                " Read one line from STDIN and save the result in Q.                  ";
    {        }=     " Find the first element q ∊ Q that yields a truthy value:            ";
     +              "   Execute L += [q].                                                 ";
      _Q,*Q#        "   Push (L * len(Q)).index(Q).                                       ";
            !       "   Compute the logical NOT of the index.                             ";
               ;    " Discard the last q. This leaves L on the stack.                     ";
```

Answer (score 8):

### Regex (.NET flavour), <s>23</s> 22 bytes

```
.+?(?=(.*$)(?<=^\1.*))
```

This will match the required period as a substring.

[Test it here.](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=d2f91dfc-88ff-4a21-824a-b49512d0ce5d)

How does it work?

```
# The regex will always find a match, so there's no need to anchor it to
# the beginning of the string - the match will start there anyway.
.+?        # Try matching periods from shortest to longest
(?=        # Lookahead to ensure that what we've matched is actually
           # a period. By using a lookahead, we ensure that this is
           # not part of the match.
  (.*$)    # Match and capture the remainder of the input in group 1.
  (?<=     # Use a lookahead to ensure that this remainder is the same
           # as the beginning of the input. .NET lookaheads are best
           # read from right to left (because that's how they are matched)
           # so you might want to read the next three lines from the 
           # bottom up.
    ^      # Make sure we can reach the beginning of the string.
    \1     # Match group 1.
    .*     # Skip some characters, because the capture won't cover the
           # entire string.
  )
)
```

Comment: This only works if the period starts at the beginning of the string, though. That happens to be the case here, but I don't see this in the specs. Right?

Comment: @TimPietzcker See OP's comment/edit on the question: the period always starts at the beginning of the string.

Comment: [Regex Storm .Net](http://regexstorm.net/tester) seems to handle .NET as well, and it doesn't require Silverlight (unavailable on most platforms).

Comment: @Dennis Thanks, I didn't know that one!

Comment: I can't get the perl version quite right: `$_ = <>; /^(.+?)(?=\g1+)/; print $1;` gives `18349570345710975`

Comment: @tolos That's because you don't ensure that you can reach the end of the string like this. Hence it will just use the first thing that repeats at all. E.g. `aabaabaab` will probably match `a` because it repeats. I haven't found a way to solve it in PCRE yet. Dennis tried in a now deleted answer, but that one didn't fully work either. Btw, you don't need `g`.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 60

`s` is the string of digits

```
[s[:i]for i in range(len(s))if(s[:i]*len(s))[:len(s)]==s][0]
```

eg:

```
>>> s = '18349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109761834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710976183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097618349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109761834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710976183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097618349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109761834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710976183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097618349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109761834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710976183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097618349570345710975183495703457109751834957'
>>> [s[:i]for i in range(len(s))if(s[:i]*len(s))[:len(s)]==s][0]
'1834957034571097518349570345710975183495703457109751834957034571097518349570345710976'
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 14 characters

```
hf}z*lzTm<zdUz
```

Explanation:

```
implicit:      z = input()
h              head(
 f                  filter(lambda T:
  }z                                z in
    *lz                                  len(z) * 
       T                                          T,
  m                        map(lambda d:
   <zd                                  z[:d],
   Uz                                   range(len(d)))))
```

Essentially, it generates all of the initial sequences of the input, repeats each one `len(z)` times, and sees whether `z`, the input, lies within the resultant string.

---

This is not a valid answer, but a feature was recently added to Pyth, after the question was asked, that allows a 12 character solution:

```
<zf}z*lz<zT1
```

This uses the filter on integer feature.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 bytes

```
å+ æ@¶îX
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI=&code=5Ssg5kC27lg=&input=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)

-2 bytes thanks to Shaggy!

Transpiled JS Explained:

```
// U is the input string representation of the number
U
 // cumulative reduce using the '+' operator
 // the result is an array of strings length 1, 2, ..., N
 // all substrings start with the first character from input
 .å("+")
 // find the first match
 .æ(function(X, Y, Z) {
  // repeat the substring until it is as long as the input
  // and compare it to the input
  return U === U.î(X)
 })
```

Comment: 8 bytes: `å+ æ@¶îX`

Comment: Excellent :) I've seen throwing an operator into the reduce function before, but forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 125 bytes

Takes input as a string since there is no reasonable way to represent a 1000+ digit number in Java other than a string (No BigInteger please).

```java
s->{String o="";for(int i=0;java.util.Arrays.stream(s.split(o+=s.charAt(i++))).filter(b->!b.isEmpty()).count()>1;);return o;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7Y4xb4MwFIR3foXLZAthgRJKIwukDM3WKWPVwRDcPmpsZD8iIcRvpx7Sf9CpYrrT6b3vrpd3mfa3763V0nvyJsEsERjsnJJtRy7LFR2YT6Low3gm1micGg0t8SgxyN3CjQzh83Hz/iHZEl2IItXm0/oXYas4Fso6GvAEqkz0oZtPCJqfnZOz5x5dJwcazKgBqU0qz9sv6c5IIUkYY1yBDtNok9ZPDQf/Oow405C3djJIWZ0LJlyHkzPEinUT0XX22A3cTsjHsAK1oYorGucvh@OpKLPDsSjz7FQWfxA879AdukP/DzRmTETruv0A)

Comment: You can replace `String` with var. -3 bytes

Comment: @Adam Java 8 though

Comment: Oh, didn't see that.